# NextJS mongoose schema "Cannot read properties of undefined"

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I have NextJS project with Mongoose schema inside of it.
I keep getting following error on dev environment:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Village')

My model file is:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const {Schema} = mongoose;

const VillageSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    id: {type: String},
   ...
);

// prettier-ignore
export default mongoose.models.Village || mongoose.model("Village", VillageSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add optional chaining to the exported value:

```
// prettier-ignore
export default mongoose.models?.Village || mongoose.model("Village", VillageSchema);
```

Comment: Yes this solved the issue... Why did that happen all the examples didn't have optional chaining ?